# MS Bot Framework - Messages with audio attachments lost

Tags: node.js, audio, botframework, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm writing a bot in Node.js using the MS Bot Framework. To send attachments, I'm actually using the filestream buffer as the contentUrl, e.g.

```
...
var base64 = new Buffer(filedata).toString('base64');
var msg = new builder.Message()
    .setText(session, text)
    .addAttachment({
        contentUrl: util.format('data:%s;base64,%s', contentType, base64),
        contentType: contentType
});
session.send(msg);
...
```

where `contentType` is the proper mimetype for the file in question.

When I test this locally (using the Bot Framework Emulator), this works perfectly for both image and audio files - messages with image attachments display the image, and messages with audio attachments show the audiocard allowing for playback, etc.

However, when I test this through FB Messenger, the images work fine, but the audio messages just never appear in FB. Not even the text of the message comes through; it's like the entire message is lost. The dialogue simply skips over the message containing the audio attachment. I'm not even seeing any errors received server-side.

This is happening with both mp3 and wav test audio files, that are each under 1MB (smaller than many of the image files I've successfully tested).

Is there some trick to sending playable audio files to the FB Messenger channel specifically?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked to see if this is a limitation of the Facebook channel?  Some channels only let bot send certain file types, **especially** for local files, and not https hosted files.  You could also try an audio card which you can find in [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/cards-RichCards).

Comment: Thanks Jason. I did try an audio card, with the same results (message appeared to send successfully from server-side, but did not show up in FB messenger).
I've looked through the FB messenger documentation, and there doesn't seem to be any limitation there (in fact, audio files are [explicitly listed as an allowed attachment type](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages#types) in their API docs), unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I saw that too, but they also only show examples of files being sent with a URL and not local files sent with base 64.  This is a reoccurring thing, like I said many channels limit the file type when it is a local file and not a URL.  I would honestly try reaching out to FB support and ask them if it is possible for a bot to send a local audio file. Also maybe try hosting the file somewhere and see if that makes a difference, like in the sample I linked.

Comment: Alright, I'll try reaching out to FB support. Going to keep the question open in hopes that someone will have some more direct info (and/or a potential solution), but thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't (yet) able to get a response from FB support, but after further testing, it looks like there *is* a filesize limit on audio files FB Messenger will accept.

Specifically, I was able to get a sample file of ~45KB to send and display in Messenger successfully, but a larger file of ~400KB got dropped (aka seemed to send successfully from the server-side perspective, but did not show up in Messenger).

Strangely, some of my much larger image files went through, so it seems like this same limit does not exist for image attachments.

Will do some further testing, but it seems like the ultimate solution will be either to majorly compress my audio files, or to host them somewhere else instead of sending as a filestream.